# Match word length avoiding tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've got this sentence:
    `It seems to be the basic assumption of traditional philosophies that human <span style="color:#ff5e43;">intellectual</span> powers are for (abc) the purpose of accelerating our own evolution beyond the restraints of the biological determinism which binds all other living organisms.`

and I need to match words by their length. I'm using this regex syntax with the length incremented by a loop:
    `(?:^| )(\S{index})(?= |$)`

but at 5, it matches also **_<span**

At 5 instead the result should be: `seems basic human (abc) which binds other`

At this link my attempts [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/bL4eW2/6)

Comment: I'd recommend that instead of trying to deal with parsing the sentence with html in it using regex, get the sentence without html (something like [.text](https://api.jquery.com/text/)). This would be much easier than ignoring html tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `\w` instead of `\S`. See [here](http://regex101.com/r/bL4eW2/5)

`\w` means word which consists of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot an important detail: words between parenthesis and non-word characters must be matched, that's why I used `\S`. Just that specific tag must be excluded.

Comment: In that case, you should specify those things that you don't want wanna match in a char class `[^\s<>]{5}`. The fist `^` is inversion, meaning it will match anything that is NOT inside the char class. See [example](http://regex101.com/r/bL4eW2/7).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and probably the best solution here is to not use regex at all. Instead, use the power of the DOM to get rid of the unnecessary stuff, and look in the clean text only.

```
// Setup
var string = 'It seems to be the basic assumption of traditional philosophies that human <span style="color:#ff5e43;">intellectual</span> powers are for (abc) the purpose of accelerating our own evolution beyond the restraints of the biological determinism which binds all other living organisms.',
    text,
    pass = [];

// Define length
var wordlength = 5;
// Make a new div for the elements to sit in
$textNode = $(document.createElement('div')).html(string);
// Remove html tags but keep their content (e.g. the span tag)
text = $textNode.text();
// Split the text at the spaces
text = text.split(' ');
// Loop through the new array to find words with specific length
$.each(text,function(i,el){
   if (el.length === wordlength) pass.push(el);
});
```

```js
var string = 'It seems to be the basic assumption of traditional philosophies that human <span style="color:#ff5e43;">intellectual</span> powers are for (abc) the purpose of accelerating our own evolution beyond the restraints of the biological determinism which binds all other living organisms.',
    text,
    pass = [],
    wordlength = 5;

$textNode = $(document.createElement('div')).html(string);
text = $textNode.text().split(' ');
$.each(text,function(i,el){
   if (el.length === wordlength) pass.push(el);
});
document.write(pass.join(' '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```